# Show the window form modally on the other form

Tags: c#, .net

I have a window form named `form1` and on that I want to show another window form named `form2` modally so that user cannot click on anything else until the `form2` is closed but user can select only the textbox displayed on `form1`.

Comment: "form2 modally so that user cannot click on anything else until the form2 is closed"
and "but user can select only the textbox displayed on form1."
is called contradiction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it would be better if you use textbox on form2 and use form2.showdialog() in form1

Answer (score 1):

use the following code in Form1:

```
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a modeless form2, and disable all user control in form1 except the `Textbox` on form1.